# Selecting both listbox item by just selecting on one listbox item from another listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

First I'm going to select an item from `ListBox1` then if I select an item in `ListBox1`, the corresponding index of `ListBox2` should be selected also.

my code for  `ListBox1`

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
}
```

here's for `ListBox2`

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
}
```

I didn't understand the method clearly and there must be a confusion happening.

I just need help in this part and hope you guys could share some knowledge about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (listBox2.Items.Count >= listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1)
     {
          listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
     }
}

private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count >= listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1)
    {
         listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;               
    }
}
```